# SQL Join Sum tables different from single queries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join

My issue is: I have 3 tables `Invoiced`, `Expired`, `Payed`, every table has these columns:

- customer_code
- type
- amount

In Oracle I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT
    C.customer_code,
    C.type,
    SUM(C.AMOUNT)  AS AMOUNT_EXPIRED,
    SUM(F.AMOUNT)  AS AMOUNT_INVOICED,
    SUM(R.AMOUNT)  AS AMOUNT_PAYED        
  FROM Expired C
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_code, ACCOUNT, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
               FROM Invoiced
              GROUP BY customer_code, type) F
    ON C.customer_code = F.customer_code
   AND C.type = F.type
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_code, type, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
             FROM Payed
            GROUP BY customer_code, type) R
    ON C.customer_code = R.customer_code
   AND C.type = R.type
 GROUP BY C.customer_code, C.type,
          R.customer_code, R.type, 
          F.customer_code, F.type
```

I get a table with columns:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 customer_code | type | amount_expired | amount invoiced | amount payed
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but the amounts are different respect to the single queries:

```
SELECT customer_code, type, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM expired GROUP BY customer_code, type
SELECT customer_code, type, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM invoiced GROUP BY customer_code, type
SELECT customer_code, type, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM payed GROUP BY customer_code, type
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your queries are not syntactically correct . . . `ACCOUNT` and `type` are confused in the first two subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union` instead of `join`. But you should have a table to store all the customer codes and types though. And you should never use `join` when it comes aggregate functions. It's very confusing and usually produce incorrect results.

```
with CUSTOMER as (
    select CUSTOMER_CODE, TYPE from EXPIRED group by CUSTOMER_CODE, TYPE
    union 
    select CUSTOMER_CODE, TYPE from INVOICED group by CUSTOMER_CODE, TYPE
    union 
    select CUSTOMER_CODE, TYPE from PAYED group by CUSTOMER_CODE, TYPE
)
select
    c.CUSTOMER_CODE, c.TYPE
    ,(
    select sum(AMOUNT) 
    from EXPIRED 
    where CUSTOMER_CODE = c.CUSTOMER_CODE and TYPE = c.TYPE
    ) as AMOUNT_EXPIRED
    ,(
    select sum(AMOUNT) 
    from INVOICED 
    where CUSTOMER_CODE = c.CUSTOMER_CODE and TYPE = c.TYPE
    ) as AMOUNT_INVOICED
    ,(
    select sum(AMOUNT) 
    from PAYED 
    where CUSTOMER_CODE = c.CUSTOMER_CODE and TYPE = c.TYPE
    ) as AMOUNT_EXPIRED
from CUSTOMER c
order by c.CUSTOMER_CODE, c.TYPE
```

Comment: For alternative, use the `CUSTOMER` as the main table, then left join to each sum sub-queries just like your initial query.

Comment: Great! It was a sample, of course I have a customer table (with others useful fields) and it works. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your second subquery may be the reason, this may be what you expect;

```
SELECT  C.customer_code, C.type, 
    SUM(C.AMOUNT)       AS AMOUNT_EXPIRED,
    SUM(F.AMOUNT)       AS AMOUNT_INVOICED,
    SUM(R.AMOUNT)       AS AMOUNT_PAYED        
FROM      Expired C
LEFT JOIN invoiced F
ON        C.customer_code= F.customer_code
AND       C.type= F.type
LEFT JOIN payed R 
ON        C.customer_code= R.customer_code
AND       C.type= R.type

GROUP BY  C.customer_code, C.type
```